# MYSQL - Possibly FIND_IN_SET

Tags: mysql, join, where-clause, find-in-set

I'm really struggling to figure this query out:

| names | zone | zones | zone_active |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| bob | 1 | 1,2 | yes |
| bill | 0 | 3 | yes |
| james | 1 | 1,2 | yes |
| fred | 1 | 1,2 | no |
| barry | 1 | 4 | yes |

Im selecting zones '1,2' and zone_active='yes'

But it's returning all rows except Bill and Barry its seems to be ignoring the zone_active part

```
SELECT p.names, n.zone, n.zones, n.zone_active
FROM names as n
JOIN people as p ON p.names=n.names
WHERE zone IN ('1,2') AND zone_active='yes'
```

It should only return - bob, james

any ideas?

Comment: `zone IN ('1,2')`, with just one thing in the IN list, isn't very meaningful, it's the same as `zone = '1,2'`.  and if zone is an integer, it is casting the string to an integer, so is effectively `zone = 1`.  Did you mean `zone IN (1,2)` or `zones = '1,2'`?

Answer (score 0):

`IN()` does not treat a string as a list of discrete values just because the string contains commas. The value `'1,2'` is a single value, a string. So the operand will be compared to one value.

I assume `zone` is an integer (though you have not shown your table's data types, so that might be a wrong assumption). If you compare an integer to a string that has leading digits like `'1,2'`, the initial digits are converted to an integer, and then compared.

So if `zone` is an integer column, then this:

```
WHERE zone IN ('1,2')
```

Is equivalent to this:

```
WHERE zone = 1
```

This does not match the row for bill because zone is 0 and the integer conversion for `'1,2'` is 1. So `0 = '1,2'` is false.

The query *should* match the row for barry because `1 = '1,2'` is true. I wonder if you made some mistake in your question.

---

Re your comment:

> I want it to check if 1 or 2 is in the zone field

That would be:

```
WHERE zone IN (1,2) AND zone_active='yes'
```

But not:

```
WHERE zone IN ('1,2') AND zone_active='yes'
```

If you're trying to use query parameters, you need a separate parameter for each value:

```
WHERE zone IN (?, ?) AND zone_active='yes'
```

Because each parameter will be interpreted as *one* value. You can't use a single parameter for a list of values. If you try to use a parameter value of `'1,2'` that will become one string value, and that'll behave as I described above.

Some people try to fake this using FIND_IN_SET() but I would not recommend that. It will ruin any chance of optimizing the query with indexes.

Comment: zones param is a string...I want it to check if 1 or 2 is in the zone field not zones field where zone_active=yes